# Angular 2 RC5 router - nested routing

Tags: angular2-routing

**Structure**

```
app |- admin
         |- users
             |- userList.Component.ts
             |- userDetails.Component.ts
         |- admin.component.html (contains 'router-oulet')
         |- admin.component.ts
         |- admin.routes.ts
         |- admin.module.ts
    |- dogs
    |- app.component.html (contains 'router-oulet')
    |- app.component.ts
    |- app.routes.ts
    |- app.module.ts
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

    { path: 'dogs', component: DogListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'dog/:id', component: DogDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**admin.routes.ts**

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AdminGuard],
        children: [

            { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/users' },

            { path: 'users', component: AdminUserListComponent },
            { path: 'user/:id', component: AdminUserDetailsComponent },
        ]
    },

];

export const adminRouting = RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

**admin.userList.Component.ts**

```
this._router.navigate(['/admin/user/', id]);
```

trying to navigate from AdminUserList ('admin/users') to AdminUserDetails ('admin/user/someId') but with no success.

(it seems like the scroller is going further down whenever i try to navigate to the user details)

any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `pathMatch: 'full'` in admin routes for default redirect,

**admin.routes.ts**

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [

{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: [

        { path: '', redirectTo: '/admin/users', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'users', component: AdminUserListComponent },
        { path: 'user/:id', component: AdminUserDetailsComponent },
    ]
 },
];

export const adminRouting = RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes);
```

**Update**

To navigate back you have couple of ways,

```
 // In the HTML
 <a [routerLink]="['/admin']" >Back</a> or <a [routerLink]="['/admin/users']" >Back</a>

 // Or create a back function and use in click binding in HTML
 goBack = () => {
    this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
    or this.router.navigate(['/admin/users']);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ! and how do i navigate back from /admin/user/someId back to admin/users ?